# JW Player (or any video) controls in a separate location on page, or on a higher z-index

Tags: video, z-index, jwplayer

Easier to show my issue than explain it...

http://www.bgraphix.co.nz/bgraphix/sylvania/media.html

I've got a pretty frame over top of a video, so... how can I control the video now? So when you hover over the video, it displays the controls.
Is it possible to clip the video to a specific shape and then place it on top? Or make the transparent part of the top image "invisible"?
Ideally i'd like to have the "play" button as a separate image to the right somewhere. Clear as mud?

Comment: You need to create your own custom control using jwplayer API

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make your own controls.

See this example - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439411-example-a-chromeless-player

Our example here is utilizing some simple API calls to reference our JW Player embed.

For example, the play button is using our method:

```
jwplayer().play();
```

Our skip forward/backward buttons are using two methods. First, we're getting our position in the video. Next, we're adding or subtracting 5 seconds from the position for our skip/rewind buttons.

```
​jwplayer().getPosition(); position -= 5; jwplayer().seek(position);​
```

and

```
​jwplayer().getPosition(); position += 5; jwplayer().seek(position);
```